# How can a define a new column based on the first character in another column? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column, call it `df['old']` of strings like the following.

```
a1bc  
df3   
ca9se 
3as3d 
iu23
```

What I would like to do is create a new column that indicates if the value in the original column begins with one of a few characters.

Something like the following does not work as `df['old'][0]` returns `a1bc`.

```
df['new'] = df['old'][0] in ['a','b']
```

Is there a way to do this without using a loop? I don't know how to call a column and then just the first character value for that column.

Comment: I think you need `df['old'].str[0]` to access first element then use `isin` to check in list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str` to index your strings in each row, then use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if it's in your list (using `in` will lead to `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`):

```
>>> df
     old
0   a1bc
1    df3
2  ca9se
3  3as3d
4   iu23

df['new'] = df.old.str[0].isin(['a','b'])

>>> df
     old    new
0   a1bc   True
1    df3  False
2  ca9se  False
3  3as3d  False
4   iu23  False
```